# Java: Morphia how easy is it to update a Collection with new field values

Tags: java, morphia

I'm new to this,

Let's say I have Collection "`UserData`" and there are 1000 Documents in the UserData.

Now I need to add one more field called "`position`".

Can I do this, how?, or how does it work?

Looking on the wiki [Morphia](http://code.google.com/p/morphia/wiki/UsingCollections) but cannot find anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially, yeah, you can.  There are implications, but significantly less than using a traditional ORM.

With Morphia, if your persisted object has an instance variable that isn't set, its not included in the record in mongo.  So adding another instance variable is pretty straightforward for mongo to retroactively map older records - they just get `null` for that variable (in my experience).

Now if your application now absolutely depends on Position you'll have to update those 1000 records, but in general in my experience you can add the instance variable and it'll just work, easy as that.

Comment: coming from SQL it just feel good to know all 1000 are the same, dunno..Must be some fork to tell Mongo to insert it ..

Answer (score 2):

if the `UserData` is look like,

```
@Entity
UserData{
@Id
private ObjectId id;
private String name;
private int age;
}
```

and you have added 1000 documents in this Collection.

Now, you want one more field called `position`,

Just do this,

```
@Entity
UserData{
@Id
private ObjectId id;
private String name;
private int age;
private String position;//Add the field like this.
}
```

In the old 1000 documents, the value of position will be `null`.

Its the power of mongo, you can expand your data structure when ever you want.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this page can help you with your problem. http://code.google.com/p/morphia/wiki/Updating

Comment: isn't that only for updating exiting instance variable

Comment: but in morphia/mongo if you call save in a UserData with a new field, that document will be saved with that field. If you create a update method that saves all documents of a collection, with a new field, that fix you problem;

Comment: that sounds promising, how do i do an update method, i read somewhere about this but cannot find the way. Post your comment as an answer so i can accept it, if you have the solution i'll be happy